# How to make the Route53 domain point to the newly created instance in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I have 2 AWS accounts , say A and B. I have to move the ec2 instances and domains & records to the account B. 
I was able to make AMI for account A and successfully launched it in account B. I was ablee to move the domains also to account B and made new records in account B.

But the domain still points to the account A instance. Is there any delay in the process and by how much. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the name servers (NS records) of the new AWS account route53 to your domain registrar (Basically from where you purchased the domain)

Once that is done, wait for sometime now your domain will work as per the domain settings in your new account.

Comment: Thanks this fixed the issue. The problem was that I didnt update the NS records of the registered domain(new/transfered) to that of hosted domains.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the TTL value of records in your DNS. For example, if it is 3600 means need to wait 1 hour to update.